# How to get the scalar value of a function parameter which is a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to get the scalar value of a function parameter like following code does:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def test(key_value):
    tf.print(key_value.numpy())

a = tf.constant(0)
test(a)
```

But there is no numpy function when running in autograph.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is only available outside of `tf.function`, where Tensors have actual values. Within `tf.function`, you have access to a restricted API. As long as you pass the tensor to a TensorFlow op, you don't need to call `numpy`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def test(key_value):
    tf.print(key_value)

a = tf.constant(0)
test(a)
```

Have a look at [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) for more info.